# Get values from pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Hi So I have dataframe like this, which has 71 unique values in `time` column, 721 unique values in `lat` column, 1440 unique values in `lon` column and all the values in temp column are unique.

Dataframe Sample:

```
  time        latitude  longitude       temp
1950-01-01      90.0     0.00         49654.792969
1950-01-01      90.0     0.25         49654.792969
   .              .       .                .
   .              .       .                .
73715040 rows * 4 cloumn
```

Now I want to groupby using `lat` and `lon` column to get all the values of temp across all time period for all grid or pairs which will have `1038240 rows(721 lat*1440 lon)`, so I'm doing like this.

`df = df.groupby(['latitude', 'longitude'])`

Now as it is `pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object` I'm not able to access the values from it. So I'm trying to convert it into dataframe by `df.apply(pd.DataFrame)` but this is taking lot of time and my kernel is getting crash. So is there any other way to get the records, or am I doing something wrong here. Please suggest alternate way if possible.

Comment: Pandas `groupby()` instruction must come with an `aggregate()` instruction. What do you want as the third column in output? The temps comma separated?

Comment: @HenriChab yess I want all the values of temp with that lat lon pair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```py
df.groupby(['latitude', 'longitude']).aggregate(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))
```

Comment: hey it's working perfect but the order is getting bit messed up, like I was expecting first latitude and longitude to be 90.0 and 0.00, but it's coming up as -90.0 and 0.00. It's taking last latitude, is it possible to get the pair in the same order as it is in the original dataframe?

Comment: hey I used sort = False and it worked as expected. Thanks for the answer. I'm accepting it. :)

Answer (score 2):

The object type `pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy` is a list of tuples, where the first element is the groupby element and the second the dataframe for that group.

See the example below:

### Creating test dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ColA": [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3], "ColB": [5,5,6,7,7,8,8,9], "ColC": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
```

### The test dataframe

```
>>> df
   ColA  ColB  ColC
0     1     5     1
1     1     5     2
2     1     6     3
3     2     7     4
4     2     7     5
5     3     8     6
6     3     8     7
7     3     9     8
```

### Grouping dataframe

```
>>> groups = df.groupby(["ColA", "ColB"])

>>> type(groups)
<class 'pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy'>
```

### Showing results

```
>>> for group in groups:
...     g, value = group
...     print(f"Key = {g}")
...     print(value)
...     print(80*"-")
...
Key = (1, 5)
   ColA  ColB  ColC
0     1     5     1
1     1     5     2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Key = (1, 6)
   ColA  ColB  ColC
2     1     6     3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Key = (2, 7)
   ColA  ColB  ColC
3     2     7     4
4     2     7     5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Key = (3, 8)
   ColA  ColB  ColC
5     3     8     6
6     3     8     7
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### IMPORTANT

As commented by @HenriChab, using `aggregate` or, for example, `sum` will return a dataframe type not a group type

```
>>> new_df = df.groupby(["ColA", "ColB"]).sum()
>>> new_df
           ColC
ColA ColB
1    5        3
     6        3
2    7        9
3    8       13
     9        8
```

Finally you can reset the index.

```
>>> new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

>>> new_df
   ColA  ColB  ColC
0     1     5     3
1     1     6     3
2     2     7     9
3     3     8    13
4     3     9     8
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much fo the detailed answer! :)